# Creating a for statement out of dataframe by using each row as a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

df:

```
A   B   C   D   E
R   1   0.5 YES YTD
A   0   0.7 No  QTD
H   1   0.9 YES MTD
U   1   0.9 No  MTD
L   0   0.2 YES QTD
```

I am trying to read this dataframe with an aim to create variables from the values provided.

For example:

```
row_list = [] 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    my_list =[row['A'], row['B'], row['C'], row['D'], row['E'], row['F']]
    row_list.append(my_list) 
row_list
```

Now, I have to assign variables like this. This does not seem to be a sensible way to assign values.

```
A = row_list[0][0]
B = row_list[0][1]
C = row_list[0][2]
D = row_list[0][3]
E = row_list[0][4]
```

How can i use the above dataframe to create a if statement as follows for each row of the dataframe:

```
for i in row_list:
    <do something if A = 'R'>
    <do something if B = 1>
    <do something if C > 0.5 >
    <do something if D = 'YES'>
    <do something if E = 'QTD'>
```

What am I missing here to make this execution easier and more automated?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do based on your if-statement? That's quite crucial to the answer.

Comment: Why don't you just work with columns?

Comment: I don't have issues with the loop I am trying to read the row from df and assign each column value of the first row to a different variable so that it can be used as a list in for loop. something like ```for A, B, C, D, E in row_list:```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want:

```
# Pseudo code:
# if A equals 'R':
#     D = 'YES'
# else:
#     D = 'No'
```

does this:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x == 'R' else 'No')
```

does it aswell:

```
df['D'] = where(df['A'] == 'R', 'YES', 'No')
```

This automatically applies to all rows. You don't have to iterate through them.